# UIView at Index for UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios, uikit, uisegmentedcontrol

I would like to change the background color for a specific segment (not the selected segment) inside a UISegmentedControl, but it seems it's actually pretty difficult to grab the appropriate UIView for a specific segment.  I'm looking for a method like:

```
[segmentedControl viewForSegmentAtIndex:3];
```

Comment: You should look to customize it then. Something like this https://github.com/HeshamMegid/HMSegmentedControl

Answer (score 3):

Ended up doing it with a category :)

```
@interface UISegmentedControl (BP)
- (UIView *)segmentAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
@end

@implementation UISegmentedControl (BP)
- (UIView *)segmentAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    // All the views are a private subclass "UISegment", and are not ordered sanely, no problem, we can fix that
    return [self.subviews sortedArrayWithOptions:0 usingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(UIView *obj1, UIView *obj2) {
        return [@(obj1.frame.origin.x) compare:@(obj2.frame.origin.x)];
    }][index];
}
@end
```